# How to implement pagination on YouTube Api?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to display all the videos of a user YouTube channel, and in order to do so I'm trying to implement pagination with YouTube API. However, I'm having trouble storing the page tokens to every request.

```
var channelName = '*******';
var nextPageToken = "";
var prevPageToken = "";
var pid = "**********";
var counter;


begin();

function begin(){
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
            part: 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
            key: '*********************'},
            function(data){
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                    pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                    getVids(pid);

                })
            }       

    );
}


function getVids(pid){

        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 50,
                playlistId: pid,   
                key: '******************'},
                function(data){
                    counter = data.pageInfo.totalResults;
                    var output;

                    nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;

                    prevPageToken = data.prevPageToken; 
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item){

                        total = data.pageInfo.totalResults;

                        videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                        videoTitle = item.snippet.title;


                        videoImg = item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url;
                        output = `<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
                            <div class="card" style="width: auto; border:none; border-radius:0%; background-image:url('${videoImg}');background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                            <div class="card-body card-mod">
                                <p class="card-text" id="nombre-mod" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold !important; color:#f2f2f2!important; font-size:20px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #141313;">${videoTitle}</p>
                            </div>
                                <a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId} class="stretched-link"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;

                        //Append to results list

                        $('#results').append(output);

                    })

                    saveNext(nextPageToken);

                    for (i = 0; i < counter ; i++){
                        nextPage(pid,nextPageToken);

                        counter = counter - 50;
                    }

                }





        );




    }
```

Here I try to store the nextPageToken value to pass it to new requests.

```
        function saveNext(f){
        nextPageToken = f;

        return nextPageToken;
    }

function nextPage(pid, nextPageToken){

        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 50,
                playlistId: pid,
                pageToken : nextPageToken,          
                key: 'AIzaSyCLj1raUEFRewglexWcIz5Z_roLYCAkpFw'},
                function(data){
                    var output;
                    nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
                    saveNext(nextPageToken);
                    prevPageToken = data.prevPageToken;
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item){


                        total = data.pageInfo.totalResults;

                        videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                        videoTitle = item.snippet.title;


                        videoImg = item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url;
                        output = `<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
                            <div class="card" style="width: auto; border:none; border-radius:0%; background-image:url('${videoImg}');background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                            <div class="card-body card-mod">
                                <p class="card-text" id="nombre-mod" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold !important; color:#f2f2f2!important; font-size:20px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #141313;">${videoTitle}</p>
                            </div>
                                <a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId} class="stretched-link"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;

                        $('#results').append(output);

                    })



                }                


        );


    }
```

So far I can only pass through one nextPageToken value to my requests and can't seem to store the next tokens on a playlist with almost 600 videos.